# Why the sub links won't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the links in the slideDown menu.

The Link's aren't clickable why?

You can see it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evolutio/Mxvdq/)

My jQuery code is:

```
$('.links').hide();
$('.header a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.links').slideToggle('normal');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You're using `preventDefault()`, which prevents the default action. If you only want the top level anchors to be affected, change your selector to `$('.header > a')`

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault()` if you want to make link clickable

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted! It is obviously a new learner, and as to any experienced programmer this mistake is obvious, to learners it will be a milestone! It is not a bad question, or a horribly formatted one, just one with an easy answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `.header a` will affect all anchors contained within `.header`, which you don't want. You only want to `toggle()` when an anchor, which is a direct child of `.header` is clicked.

```
$('.header > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.links').slideToggle('normal');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `e.preventDefault()` it will prevent default action which is `click()`

```
$('.header a').click(function(e) {
            $(this).next('.links').slideToggle('normal');
            //e.preventDefault();
        });
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxvdq/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your using `e.preventDefault();` which stops the default action which is going to happen i.e HREF moving the page to the new location. If you remove `e.preventDefault()` your links will become 'active' again.

**Updated Code**

```
$('.header a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.links').slideToggle('normal');
});
```

From the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

`e.preventDefault()` - If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.